# Generating Normal map from a Image with a given Albedo map

Tags: graphics, normal-mapping

I am working on a research problem part of which involves generating normal map from a given image of a rusted object. I searched the internet for techniques to achieve the above and apparently crazybump is mentioned a lot. I tried it but it didn't produce the desirable effects. Also I am looking for a method which draws inspiration from an existing research paper not some closed source software. I turned my attention to the technique described in the this [paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~barron/BarronMalikTR2013.pdf). Results from this technique are satisfactory for normal objects because of bias in the training data but it doesn't work very well in the case of rusted objects. 
After this I focussed my attention on generating Albedo map (the above problem would become more solvable if Albedo map is obtained). Fortunately I am able to generate pretty good albedo maps for images of rusted objects. I used [this paper's](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.dongallen.com/project/appgen/appgen.htm&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEuiVLAOzYgVuB4JOgi0VYNeal2bA) approach to generate Albedo maps. Now I want to know a good technique to get Normal map given an image and it's corresponding Albedo map. To give you an idea of what kind of images I am working with I am attaching a sample.

Links to research material would be really appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Rusted image]

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.cgtextures.com/content.php?action=tutorial&name=normalmap

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the source code implementation of the NVidia Texture Tools [createNormalMap()](https://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/source/browse/trunk/src/nvimage/NormalMap.cpp) function. Or you might even incorporate their library in your project.

Also, in the book [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics](http://www.mathfor3dgameprogramming.com/) there is a discussion on chapter 7 about bump mapping construction, which might be worth reading.